# how to select msg display in edit box and create txt file in application

Tags: android

I have created a list, messagebox and main activity java file.
when user clicks on inbox button show all inbox msg of your mobile.
when you select inbox msg that display on automatically my mainactivity.java in edit box and when you click save button the create text(.txt) file in my application

I forward to all xml file and it is important how to select msg automatically display on edit box and when click on save create .txt file in application.
       **when you click on save button those of edit box msg create txt file and txt file data is same edit box msg.**

```
 **Mainactivity.java**
    package com.example.sharedpreference;

    import com.example.sharedpreference.R;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private Button send,checkdata,Inbox,checkmsg;
        private EditText phoneno,editText2;
        private TextView Display,message,SMSm;
        //private Button save;
         String Message,PhoneNo,SMSBody1,phoneNumber1;
         /*public void getSmsDeatils(String SMSBody,String phoneNumber){
             SMSBody1=SMSBody;
             phoneNumber1=phoneNumber;
         }*/
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            phoneno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

            Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
            message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            //SMSm=(TextView) findViewById (R.id.etSmsBody);
            //Inbox=(Button) findViewById(R.id.inbox);
            send=(Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
            checkdata=(Button) findViewById(R.id.checkdata);
            //checkmsg=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        checkdata.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 PhoneNo=phoneno.getEditableText().toString();
                Message=message.getText().toString();

                /*Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);*/

                Display.setText("Phone Number-:"+PhoneNo+"\n"+"Message-:"+Message);
                //display.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }

        });

        /*Inbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            private Context context;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,MessageBox.class);
                startActivity(intent);   

            }

        });*/


        Intent i = getIntent();
        String val = "";

        if(i.hasExtra("value"))
              val = i.getStringExtra("value");

        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     editText2.setText(val);
     //checkmsg=(Button) findViewById(R.id.checkmsg);
     /*checkmsg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Object result = editText2.getText().toString();
             Intent i = new Intent();
             i.putExtra("MESSAGE", (Boolean) result);
             Intent in = null;
            startActivity(in); 
         }
     });*/


        Inbox=(Button) findViewById(R.id.inbox);
        Inbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //private Context context;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageBox.class);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Intent intent = new Intent(context,MessageBox.class);
                //startActivity(intent); 
                 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MessageBox.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

            }
        });



        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

                sendSMSMessage();
              }

            //@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT)
            //@SuppressLint("NewApi")
            private void sendSMSMessage() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("SEND SMS","");
                String message=Display.getText().toString();
                try{
                    SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage("7666433328", null,message,null,null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS Failed,please try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            });
    }

        }
```

**MessageBox.java**
        package com.example.sharedpreference;

```
    /***
     *    Application Name : MessageBox 
     *    Author : Vimal Rughani
     *    Website : http://pulse7.net
     *    For more details visit http://pulse7.net/android/read-sms-message-inbox-sent-draft-android/
     */
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MessageBox extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        // GUI Widget
        Button btnSent, btnInbox, btnDraft;
        TextView lblMsg, lblNo;
        ListView lvMsg;

        // Cursor Adapter
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.messagebox);

            // Init GUI Widget
            btnInbox = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInbox);
            btnInbox.setOnClickListener(this);



            lvMsg = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMsg);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (v == btnInbox) {

                // Create Inbox box URI
                Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

                // List required columns
                String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

                // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
                // Provider
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

                // Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
                Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

                // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
                adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
                        new String[] { "body", "address" }, new int[] {
                                R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber });
                lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            /*if (v == btnSent) {

                // Create Sent box URI
                Uri sentURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");

                // List required columns
                String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

                // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
                // Provider
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

                // Fetch Sent SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
                Cursor c = cr.query(sentURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

                // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
                adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
                        new String[] { "body", "address" }, new int[] {
                                R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber });
                lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            if (v == btnDraft) {
                // Create Draft box URI
                Uri draftURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/draft");

                // List required columns
                String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

                // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
                // Provider
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

                // Fetch Sent SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
                Cursor c = cr.query(draftURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

                // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
                adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
                        new String[] { "body", "address" }, new int[] {
                                R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber });
                lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);

            }*/


        }
    }
```

**list.java**
        package com.example.sharedpreference;

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class list extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener{

         TextView txt;
         String result;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.row);
             String[] items = null;
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
            txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMsg);

             txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*
                        result = txt.getText().toString();
                        Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.putExtra("MessageFromsecondActivity", result);
                        setResult(1, i);

                        finish();
        */
                    }
                });
    }

        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub        
            String val = ((TextView) v).getText().toString().trim();
            CharSequence[] items = null;
            txt.setText(items[position]);          
            Intent i = new Intent(list.this, MessageBox.class);
            i.putExtra("value", val);
            //Intent in = null;
            startActivity(i);  
        }
       /* @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
            return true;
        }*/

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }   
    }
```

**all xml files
this is my activity_xml file. In select msg from Inbox that display on edit box and when create save button generate txt file in my application**

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:text="Please Enter your phone no "
         android:gravity="center" 
           android:background="#00FFFF"
android:textColor="#000000"
           android:textSize="20dp"
           />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/text_id"
         android:ems="10"
         android:inputType="number"
         android:maxLength="10" >

         <requestFocus />
     </EditText>

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
         android:text="Message"
         android:textSize="20dp" 
         android:textColor="#000000"
          android:background="#00FFFF"
          android:gravity="center" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
         android:text="Please check my Information in eTMS" 
          android:textSize="18dp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


     <Button
         android:id="@+id/send"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
         android:text="send" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/checkdata"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/send"
          android:text="Check Data" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/EditText1"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_height="75dp"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/send"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:ems="7"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/inbox"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText1"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:text="Inbox" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/save"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText1"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/inbox"
          android:text="Msg Check" />

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/editText2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/EditText1"
          android:ems="10"
          android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: what problem are you facing?? Post log cat if any

Comment: when I select Inbox msg that not display on my editbox and please give code how to create txtfile from editbox when i click on save button

Comment: when I select inbox msg that display on my editbox than I click on save button and create txt file

Comment: but problem is selected inbox msg do not display on edit box of main activity. Class from list view. Please check list.java

Comment: @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub        
            String val = ((TextView) v).getText().toString().trim();
            CharSequence[] items = null;
            txt.setText(items[position]);          
            Intent i = new Intent(list.this, MessageBox.class);
            i.putExtra("value", val);
            //Intent in = null;
            startActivity(i);  
        }

Answer (score 0):

Code to write to file present in `EditText`
Just call below method in `onclick` event of save button

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```

Comment: In `MessageBox.java` you are not getting any value through `intent`. so whatever values you are trying to pass through `activity` is not getting transferred to `MessageBox.java`